# Реализация метода класса в PHP

Tags: php, ооп

У меня есть класс Person:

```
<?php class Person {
          public $name;
          public function __construct($name) { 
              $this->name = $name;
          }
          public function ShowData() {
                 ...
          };
       }
?>
```

И производной класс:

```
<?php class Student extends Person {
          public $education;
          public $place;
          public function __construct ($name, $education, $place) { 
              parent::__construct($name);
              $this->education = $education;
              $place->place= $place;
          }
       }
?>
```

Помогите мне реализовать метод ShowData(), который показывает данные объекта класса Student ($education, $place) или данные любого другого объекта класса производного от Person.

Comment: Это как? родитель должен знать о значении в наследнике? Это неправильно

Comment: Обновил ответ. 1. Перенес все что нужно в родительский класс. 2. Сделал параметры `private`.

Comment: одного меня смутило выражение `походной класс` что ли? это вообще что?

Comment: я имел ввиду производной класс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс должен отвечать только за то состояние, которое сам порождает.
Ответственность за всё остальное он должен делегировать потомкам, через переопределение методов(как `getData`) или через позднее статическое связывание(через static, как в `getFullData`)

Как-то так:

```
class Person {
  public $name;
  public function __construct($name) { 
    $this->name = $name;
  }
  public function getData() {
    return ['name' => $this->name];
  }
  // демонстрация позднего статического связывания
  public final function getFullData() {
    return static::getData();
  }
}
```

И дочерний класс:

```
class Student extends Person {
  public $education;
  public $place;
  public function __construct ($name, $education, $place) { 
    parent::__construct($name);
    $this->education = $education;
    $this->place = $place;
  }
  public function getData() {
    return array_merge(parent::getData(), [
      'education' => $this->education,
      'place' => $this->place
    ]);
  }
 }
```

Клиентский код:

```
 $s = new Student('Alex', 'science', 'MIT');
 var_dump($s->getData());
 var_dump($s->getFullData());
```

[3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/6712J)

Answer (score 0):

Главный вопрос, зачем если `education` публичное свойство?

```
public function ShowDate() {
    return $this->education;
};
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.inheritance.php

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php

**Правильное решение:**

```
<?php

class Person {
    protected $name;
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct($name, $params = []) {
        // Validators go here
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function ShowData() {
        return $this->params;
    }
}

class Student extends Person {
    public function __construct($name, $params = []) {
        if (!is_array($params) || !isset($params['education'])) {
            throw new \BadMethodCallException("Education is required");
        }

        parent::__construct($name, $params);
    }
}

$student = new Student('Name', ['education' => 'some']);
var_dump( $student->ShowData());
var_dump( $student->ShowData()['education']);
```

Можно ещё и через http://php.net/manual/ru/book.reflection.php но сильно не советую.

Comment: самое странное и страшное, что `ShowDate` находится в родителе, а `education` в наследнике. и автор хочет из родителя вызвать поле ребенка, похоже

Comment: @АлексейШиманский И поздние версии PHP не любят наследовать методы когда количество параметров не совпадает... Тут проблемы глубже :)

Comment: Я имел в виду что ShowDate() должна быть универсальной и показывать любие даные, например если я создам новый походной класс и в него есть свойство $place, то функция должна показать данные обькта даного класса.

Comment: А этот код return $this->education; возвращает только $education

Comment: @MarianGryntsiv Тогда у вас не правильна поставленная задача. Сейчас поправлю

Comment: @MarianGryntsiv Ну и я так понял `ShowDate` => `ShowData`

Comment: @MarianGryntsiv Если понял правильно, то этот вариант подойдет лучше.

Comment: @MarianGryntsiv Можно ещё и через http://php.net/manual/ru/book.reflection.php но сильно не советую.

Answer (score 0):

Вы ошиблись лишь в этом: **__construct<strike>or</strike>**

```
class Person {
    public $name;
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function ShowDate() {
        print_r($this->name);
}
}

class Student extends Person {
    public $education;
    public function __construct($name, $education) {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->education = $education;
    }
}

$student = new Student('Vasya','Bad');
echo $student->education;
```

Comment: Оно как бы правильно, но функция должна вернуть значение, а внешний(вызывающий) код печатать.

Comment: Ну и автор вопроса хотел `education` а не `name`

Answer (score 0):

Как заметил [@Kirill Korushkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/236197/kirill-korushkin) ошибка в `__constructor`.

Так-же если обращаемся к `Person()` добавил проверку и в этом случаи отдаем `Null`.

```
class Person {
    public $name;
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function ShowDate() {
        if (isset($this->education)) {
            return $this->education;
        } else {
            return Null;
        }
    }
}

class Student extends Person {
    public $education;
    public function __construct($name, $education) {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->education = $education;
    }
}

$student = new Student('Name','Education');
echo $student->ShowDate().PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного более гибкое решение.

Мы вводим абстрактный класс `Container`, за набор полей в котором, отвечает конкретный потомок:

```
abstract class Container {
  protected $data = [];
  protected static function getFields() {
    return [];
  }
  public function __construct(array $data = []) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      if (isset($this->$key)) {
        $this->$key = $value;
      }
    }
  }
  public function __isset($key) {
    return in_array($key, static::getFields());
  }
  public function __get($key) {
    if (!isset($this->$key)) {
      throw new \Exception("Unknown field $key");
    }
    return isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key]: null;
  }
  public function __set($key, $value) {
    if (!isset($this->$key)) {
      throw new \Exception("Unknown field $key");
    }
    $this->data[$key] = $value;
  }
  public function getData() {
    return $this->data;
  }
}
```

Всё, что нужно сделать в дочерних классах - переопределить метод `getFields`:

```
class Person extends Container {
  protected static function getFields() {
    return array_merge(parent::getFields(), ['name']);
  }
}
class Student extends Person {
  protected static function getFields() {
    return array_merge(parent::getFields(), ['education', 'place']);
  }
}

$john = new Person(['name' => 'John']);
$bob = new Person();
$bob->name = 'Bob';
$mike = new Student(['name' => 'Mike', 'education' => 'High School']);
$mike->place = 'Irvine, CA';
var_dump([
  'john' => $john->getData(),
  'bob' => $bob->getData(),
  'mike' => $mike->getData(),
]);
```

Comment: Неплохое начало для какого-нибудь `ActiveRecord` :)